# Eclipse - ADT plugin not auto-completing xml

Tags: android, eclipse, macos, installation, xml-layout

I am only getting autocomplete in my xml layout when i type "android:" I want to get it whenever I press cmd+space. I am using a mac

[image]

Comment: Isn't cmd+space is for spotlight. Did you try CTRL+space?

Comment: I disabled the spotlight and configured cmd+space...its working when I type "android:"....

Answer (score 1):

Go to

```
Eclipse -> Preferences -> XML -> XML Files - > Editor -> Content Assist
```

and tick all `proposals` checkboxes to allow this.

**EDIT :** Also tick `Automatically make suggestions`  and `Insert single proposals automatically` checkboxes.

[image]

Comment: I can find that " all proposals to allow this". I added screenshot of prefrences

Comment: Am I missing anything from my screenshot? Am I on the correct page?

Answer (score 0):

Open Preferences and in the search type XML,  you would find on the left pane a XML hierarchy and under editor you will have content assist. Just tick all the boxes there are in this page and you are good to go!

Comment: I did this see my screenshot above. What am I missing?

Comment: Sometime assist stops working for me, sorry but restarting eclipse has fixed it. Done that ?

Answer (score 0):

Window--->Preferences----->General------->Keys, find Content Assist and set attribute **Binding** as **cmd + space**, and attribute **When** as **Editing in Structured Text Editors**, if it still not work, right click on your xml file, choose open with, try to use **Android Menu Editor**. Good luck.

Comment: doesnt work..tried to open with Android Menu Editor but I didnt see it open with "Andorid common XML Editor"

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:
I needed to unselect in my mac SystemPref --> keyboard-->shortcuts there was a command "select the previous input source"

Answer (score 0):

All You want is code promption whatever you enter.

**Eclipse** -> **Preferences** -> **XML** -> **XML Files** - > **Editor** -> **Content Assist**

Then input "**prompt when these characters are inserted**" with

```
@+<=:abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
```

[image: image to show where to input]